# How could I know which image is displayed in datagridview column C# .net

Tags: c#, image, winforms, datagridview, datacolumn

I have a datagridview which has 2 columns, one is the name of the file and the other one is a column that has image that could have a red or green image.

I want to know how could I get the value to know which image is displayed in the datagridview column as follow:

Note: By Default is red, but it will change to green once you do something with that file.

[image: Image with the red image]

[image: Image with the green image]

How I added those images was with a image list as follow:

```
ImageList icons = new ImageList();
icons.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
    "..\\..\\images", "red.png")));
icons.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
    "..\\..\\images", "green.png")));
```

and are loaded to the datagridview as follow:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(
    Path.Combine(DataBaseConfiguration.WPRPath, "CR" + _number)))
{
    if (!file.Contains("~$"))
    {
        dgvWprFiles.Rows.Add(new object[] { Path.GetFileName(file), icons.Images[0] });
    }
}
```

Well, the exactly question is: how to know when the column has red or green image?

thanks.

Comment: I can't see how a red or green image is decided on in the first place?

Comment: Keep a third column[hidden] which would store values against the _red_ or _green_ circles and then use it for whatever you gotta do with it. for eg, for red store 1 in the third column and for green store 0. Do this according to the same logic you are displaying the red or green circles

Comment: Or keep a flag in the Cell's Tag

Comment: @TaW Tag would require casting though. to retrieve the values. but ya that's also possible

Comment: @Equalsk, by default is red, and is asigned in `icons.Images[0]` it will be changing according you going reviewing it, but @nobody answer sounds perfect! in that way I can have a value for the image.

Comment: An advantage of @Nobody's idea is also that you can change the images later if you want to, without breaking your code.

Answer (score 0):

Those green and red images are most likely representing a Boolean value. You should be working with that Boolean value, not trying to re-verse engineer it via the image!

Unless you are doing screen scraping/atomation, you should not care what image is dispalyed. That is a minor detail of the Display side. And if you are doing screen scraping then the question should be rewored accordingly.

It would help a ton if you told us wich [.NET Display technology](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/83f267cc-7478-445a-b747-295ba88870bb/frameworks-programming-for-net-display-technologies-and-the-like?forum=csharpgeneral) you are a using. Even how you display a boolean as a iamge can varry greatly between those, and so does the answer.

Comment: Oh boy. This answer is on some higher level of awesomeness :) kindly read the question again and then the comments below it. Ciao :]

Comment: @Nobody: Please show me where the Display technology is specified. Because in WPF/UWP I can do that without a hidden column: I just change how booleans are displayed at **this point** via a type targetting tempalte, a row tempalte, a converter or a tigger.